# I'm getting something wrong with the paths of my .mp3 file when using flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to play an audio file on my flask based website. Here is my code, html, then python(flask app)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Text To Speech</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Text To Speech Converter</h1>

    <form action="/submit" method="post">
        <p>Text:</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="nm"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    </form>

    <audio id="player" src="/output.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <div> 
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button> 
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button> 
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Python

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
        return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/submit", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def input():
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.form["nm"]
        synthesize_text_file(text)
        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

synthesize_text_file just returns an output .mp3 file in my folder.

My files look like

Root

--Flask python

--CSS

--output.mp3 (this file gets uploaded here after running synthesize_text_file())

--Templates (folder for flask)

-----index.html

Can someone help to find which directory my audio file is in, keep in mind that i am running the flask http://127.0.0.1:5000/ server which might change something.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to create a static folder and use this instead

```
 <audio id="player" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='output.mp3') }}" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```